# css - Bootstrap - Vertically align form with form-control input-sm in navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I can't seem to be able to vertically align a form with "input-sm" that is placed within the navbar.  If the inputs to the form are not the same height as the navbar, it appears that they get top aligned.  I was hoping there might be a way to do this without manually adjusting the padding or margin-top.  Any ideas?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Example</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
          <button class="navbar-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-main">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navbar-main">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active">
              <a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span> Home</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span> About</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span> Contact</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="search">
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="email" class="form-control input-sm" name="email" placeholder="Email">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="password" class="form-control input-sm" name="password" placeholder="Password">
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Sign In</button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-cCueBR6CsyA4/9szpPfrX3s49M9vUU5BgtiJj06wt/s=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>


</html>
```

[image]
It doesn't look too bad as is, I just want to figure out how to do it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest thing to do is adjust the margins as you mentioned. That's how Bootstrap does it.

```css
.navbar-form {
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

The second simplest would be to use `flexbox` if you're able to.

```css
.navbar-form {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
/* Items will butt up next to each other using flexbox so the inline
spacing that existed before will be gone. So we replicate it. */
.navbar-form > .form-group {
    margin-right: 0.25rem;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @hungerstar!  I guess that is the simplest route.